# segfault on exit(EXIT_FAILURE) but not with error(EXIT_FAILURE, ...)

Tags: c, gdb, segmentation-fault, getopt

I'm using `getopt_long` in a program ([source here](http://github.com/marcoms/btcwatch)), and, when testing its behaviour when given a invalid long option (`--stack-overflow`), and I get:

```
[marcoms@baguette16 btcwatch]$ ./btcwatch --stack-overflow
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

For context, its in the `getopt_long()` loop, i.e.:

```
while((opt = getopt_long(argc,
                         argv,
                         OPTSTRING,
                         long_options,
                         &longopt_i)) != -1)
{

    ...

    default:
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
```

Instead of:

```
error(EXIT_FAILURE, 0, "unknown option !?");
```

(The `exit()` code `SIGSEGV`s)

**The crazy thing is, `default` should not be** (and is not, according to `gdb`), **executed.**

`gdb` shows that it crashes immediately on the `getopt_long()` call,

```
(gdb) start --stack-overflow    
Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe598) at src/main.c:96
96      btcdbg("main()");
(gdb) s
btcdbg (fmt=0x403260 "main()") at src/btcutil.c:50
50  }
(gdb) 
main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe598) at src/main.c:118
118     const struct option long_options[] = {
(gdb) 
211     api_err.err = false;
(gdb) 
212     colour = false;
(gdb) 
213     found_path = false;
(gdb) 
214     fp = NULL;
(gdb) 
215     n = 1.0;
(gdb) 
216     newlp = NULL;
(gdb) 
217     pn = argv[0];
(gdb) 
218     reverse = false;
(gdb) 
219     verbose = false;
(gdb) 
221     strcpy(currcy, "USD");
(gdb) 
223     setlocale(LC_ALL, "");  // sets the locale to the system's default
(gdb) 
225     while((opt = getopt_long(
(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7643e2c in __strncmp_sse2 () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

But when it is run with `error()` instead of `exit()`, it proceeds normally:

```
(gdb) start --stack-overflow
Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe598) at src/main.c:96
96      btcdbg("main()");
(gdb) s
btcdbg (fmt=0x4032a0 "main()") at src/btcutil.c:50
50  }
(gdb) 
main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe598) at src/main.c:118
118     const struct option long_options[] = {
(gdb) 
211     api_err.err = false;
(gdb) 
212     colour = false;
(gdb) 
213     found_path = false;
(gdb) 
214     fp = NULL;
(gdb) 
215     n = 1.0;
(gdb) 
216     newlp = NULL;
(gdb) 
217     pn = argv[0];
(gdb) 
218     reverse = false;
(gdb) 
219     verbose = false;
(gdb) 
221     strcpy(currcy, "USD");
(gdb) 
223     setlocale(LC_ALL, "");  // sets the locale to the system's default
(gdb) 
225     while((opt = getopt_long(
(gdb) 
/home/marcoms/code/btcwatch/./btcwatch: unrecognized option '--stack-overflow'
232         btcdbg("got option '%c'", opt);
(gdb) 
btcdbg (fmt=0x4032a8 "got option '%c'") at src/btcutil.c:50
50  }
(gdb) 
main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe598) at src/main.c:233
233         switch(opt) {
(gdb) 
236                 help(pn, optarg);
(gdb) 
help (prog_nm=0x7fffffffe8d8 "/home/marcoms/code/btcwatch/./btcwatch", topic=0x0) at src/btcutil.c:69
69      btcdbg("help()");
(gdb) 
btcdbg (fmt=0x403bfc "help()") at src/btcutil.c:50
50  }
(gdb) 
help (prog_nm=0x7fffffffe8d8 "/home/marcoms/code/btcwatch/./btcwatch", topic=0x0) at src/btcutil.c:71
71      char currcies[][3 + 1] = {
(gdb) 
101     char topics[][16] = {
(gdb) 
117     if(!topic) {
(gdb) 
118         bputs("Usage: "); bputs(prog_nm); bputs(" [OPTION]\n");
(gdb) 
Usage: /home/marcoms/code/btcwatch/./btcwatch [OPTION]
119         bputs(
(gdb) 
Get and monitor Bitcoin trade information

Options:       Long options:
  -C             --compare              comare current price with stored price
  -S             --store                store current price
  -a             --all                  equivalent to -pbs
  -b             --buy                  print buy price
  -c CURRENCY    --currency=CURRENCY    set conversion currency
  -n AMOUNT      --amount=AMOUNT        set the amount to convert
  -o             --colour, --color      enable use of colour
  -p             --ping                 check for a successful JSON response
  -r             --reverse              convert currency to Bitcoin
  -s             --sell                 print sell price
  -v             --verbose              increase verbosity

  -h [topic]     --help[=topic]         print this help, or help designated by topic
                                        use --help=topics for available topics
  -V             --version              print version number

Report bugs to marco@scannadinari.co.uk
btcwatch home page: <https://github.com/marcoms/btcwatch>
142         exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
(gdb) 
[Inferior 1 (process 25752) exited normally]
```

At this point, I really am stumped. What could be causing the segfault? Of course, I could just use `error()` instead of exit, but that's incredibly unsatisfying.

Comment: Please post your whole code, ideally in a [short, self-contained, correct, compilable example](http://sscce.org/).  You're likely running into some type of Undefined Behavior due to some memory error, but it's impossible to say without seeing all of the code.  Have you tried running it with [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: https://github.com/marcoms/btcwatch/blob/master/src/main.c#L118 is the relevant part. At least its compilable...

http://pastebin.ca/2514429 contains `valgrind`'s output.

Comment: To the editor of my question, (I can't review due to rep) is a dislike of my coding style reason enough for an edit? Personally, I don't know how you can live with yourself, mixing tabs with spaces...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your options array is not properly terminated:

```
    const struct option long_options[] = {
            // ...
            // This is the last element
            {
                    .name = "verbose",
                    .has_arg = no_argument,
                    .flag = NULL,
                    .val = 'v'
            }
    };
```

[`getopt_long(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long) requires that the options array be terminated with all zeros so that it knows how big the array is -- notice that you never actually pass the array size into `getopt_long`.  So what's happening is it's walking past the end of your array, looking for the terminator, and then it starts reading memory out-of-bounds, which Valgrind rightly complains about.  Undefined Behavior results.

The fix is simple:

```
const struct option long_options[] = {
            // ...
            {
                    .name = "verbose",
                    .has_arg = no_argument,
                    .flag = NULL,
                    .val = 'v'
            },

            // Array terminator
            {0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

Comment: @marcoms: Yeah, it's kind of buried in the documentation, so it's very easy to miss.  Whenever you pass an array to a function, you should always be wary if that function doesn't also take the array length -- that's usually an indication that something unusual is afoot.  Personally I'd prefer it if `getopt_long` took the array length as a parameter rather than using a sentinel, but obviously it's far too late to change the API.